# gatsby-source-graphql only shows 10 results

Tags: gatsby, wp-graphql, gatsby-plugin

I'm want to fetch data from a wordpress site and currently when I pass the query to show all the pages the site has it only returns 10 of 64, is there an option under gatsby-source-graphql resolver in gatsby-config.js to show more results?

Comment: Please provide some code, at least your `gatsby-config.js` or your GraphQL query. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is somehow with WP

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this issue?

Comment: I know that setting the limit on your query to a higher value with allow you to query up to a 100 items but I'm looking for a solution which allows you to query more than 100 items.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the same issue with Graphql only returning the first 10 comments. I was able to get around this issue by specifying a `first` value in my query.

```
query {
    comments (first: 500) {
      ...
    }
}
```

The current GraphQL Edge schema likely has 10 as a default value for `first`.